# Bootstrap column re-ordering and 2 column spanning. Is my layout possible?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm using bootstrap and trying to create the following layouts in desktop and mobile. Essentially there are 3 columns across the page, with the far right column being akin to a sidebar of dynamic length. Boxes A and B are for important information while box D is for the "main content" of the page, i.e. everything else.

DESKTOP VIEW

|...... A .......| |....B....| |....C....|

|..............D..............| |....C....|

|..............D..............| |....C....|

|..............D..............| |....C....|

|..............D..............|

MOBILE VIEW

|........A.......|

|........B.......|

|........C.......|

|........D.......|

In mobile view I want the boxes to appear in order, A,B,C and D.

In dekstop view I want D to start right below A and B, spanning both their widths. With standard bootstrap I can't put A,B and C in the same row as D would not start until after the end of C. I also can't nest A, B and D in a column because then in mobile it would output A,B,D,C.

I've looked in to bootstrap column re-ordering but I can't see how that would work in my situation. Maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Most important parts are @media query and float: right. Please note that the media query doesnt work inside the "Run code snippet" box but it will work properly outside.

```css
.block-a {
 background: red;
 height: 50px;
}

.block-b {
 background: green;
 height: 50px;
}

.block-c {
 background: yellow;
 height: 150px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .block-c {
  float: right;
 }
}

.block-d {
 background: pink;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 block-a">A</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 block-b">B</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 block-c">C</div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 block-d">D</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! tested outside and it worked perfectly, thank you for your help!